# Web service that doesn't respond with values

Tags: android, web-services

I'm building an app which connects to various web services via ksoap2. Most of the services provide some sort of response in the form of a string which I use in the app, however one of the services doesn't actually provide a response to be used it simply takes the inputted vales and the .net service updates the relevant DB tables.

Would the set up and call to the service be the same as to the other services that I get information back from? My code is as follows (Sorry if this is a riduculously obvious question - I'm quite new to Android);

```
 SoapObject Request = 
new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

Request.addProperty("Sub_Seq",Sub_Seq);
Request.addProperty("Start_Time",startDate.toString());
Request.addProperty("End_Time",endDate.toString());
Request.addProperty("Status",Status_Id);

SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = 
new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

envelope.dotNet = true;

envelope.setOutputSoapObject(Request);

aht = new AndroidHttpTransport(URL);

try {

aht.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

}

catch (Exception e)

{

e.printStackTrace();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you're using ksoap2.
If you want to send complex objects like 'Status_Id' you have to call addMapping() :

```
envelope.addMapping(NAMESPACE, "Status_Id", new Status_Id().getClass());
```

where NAMESPACE is something like:

```
http://pack1.pack2.your_app.org/xsd"
```

And 'Status_Id' must implements KvmSerializable. 
More info : http://seesharpgears.blogspot.com/2010/10/ksoap-android-web-service-tutorial-with.html